matplotlib ellipse englobing points
How to find the ideal angle to place all the points in the ellipse ? I would like to create an ellipse which surrounds all the points on the graph, ellipse with the minimum size (it means that the furthest points will be on the graph of the ellipse).
'
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse

# Données des points (abscisses et ordonnées)
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [7, 12, 15, 19, 25]

# Calculer les moyennes des abscisses et ordonnées
centre_x = np.mean(x)
centre_y = np.mean(y)

# Calculer les écarts entre chaque point et le centre
dx = np.abs(x - centre_x)
dy = np.abs(y - centre_y)

# Trouver les valeurs maximales des écarts
max_dx = np.max(dx)
max_dy = np.max(dy)

# Utiliser ces valeurs pour définir la largeur et la hauteur de l'ellipse
largeur = 2 * max_dx
hauteur = 2 * max_dy

# Calculer l'angle idéal (en radians)
angle_rad = np.arctan2(max_dy, max_dx)

# Convertir l'angle en degrés
angle_deg = np.degrees(angle_rad)

# Créer l'ellipse
ellipse = Ellipse((centre_x, centre_y), largeur, hauteur, angle=angle_deg, fill=False, color='red')

# Créer un nuage de points avec des couleurs aléatoires pour chaque point
plt.scatter(x, y, c=np.random.rand(len(x), 3))

# Ajouter l'ellipse au graphique
plt.gca().add_patch(ellipse)

# Afficher le graphique
plt.show()

'
I have the size of the ellipse, but don't find an angle that matches to do that.

I'm afraid your approach, the ellipse centre is in the barycentre of the points, has counterexamples. Consider a degenerate ellipse, all the points laying on the x-axis, you have N-1 points at (0,0) and 1 point at (1, 0), the center is at (1/N, 0) and, following your approach, the ellipse encompassing all N points has the minor axis equal to 0 and the major axis equal to 2-2/N, while the real minimum ellipse is centered at (0.5, 0) and has a major axis equal to 1.

IIUC, you want the Minimum Volume Enclosing Ellipsoid. If so, you can use mvee from QInfer:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from qinfer.utils import mvee
from scipy import linalg


def get_mvee(points):
    A, centroid = mvee(points)
    *_, D, V = linalg.svd(A)
    radii = 1 / np.sqrt(D)

    u = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
    x = radii[0] * np.cos(u)
    y = radii[1] * np.sin(u)

    return V.T @ np.vstack([x, y]) + centroid[:, None]


x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [7, 12, 15, 19, 25]
points = np.c_[x, y]
ellipse = get_mvee(points)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(*points.T, marker=".", color="r", zorder=3)
ax.plot(*ellipse)
ax.patch.set_facecolor("whitesmoke")
ax.grid(True)

plt.show();



Yes something like this, but I got the error   from scipy.integrate import cumtrapz
ImportError: cannot import name 'cumtrapz' from 'scipy.integrate'   despites the module scipy is correctly installed in the last version (1.14.0), even when I try "from scipy.integrate import cumtrapz"

Your comment is confusing and doesn't make much sense but in short, with python 3 and the latest versions of each package, the code in the answer above actually works without any problem (otherwise, I wouldn't post an answer, including a graph). You should be more precise and explain how and where you're using the code ;).
